# Example of stress or tone on a consonant

Tags: tone, stress

Wondering if there is such thing as [stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics)) on a consonant, e.g. `t́`, `ĺ`, `ḿ`, `ś`, `ʃ́`... If so, what the example language would be. I haven't seen any on Wikipedia.

Same thing for [tone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_(linguistics)), I haven't seen any tones specified for consonants, only vowels. So using pinyin, maybe like `ť`, `š`...

Comment: It looks like [Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/31462/example-of-stress-or-tone-on-a-consonant) can have it on [ḿ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of tone on an obstruent is Logoori [kʊ̀.d́.dèè.kà] 'to cook it (class 11)'; [d́ꜜ.díi.dʒi] 'wall', where acute accent is H tone and grave is L tone. I should point out though that from a theoretical perspective, stresses and tones are not "on" segments, they are on prosodic elements which may be exhaustively characterized by some string of segments, including the case where a syllable or mora only has one segment. The argument that [kʊ̀.d́.dèè.kà] is syllabified that way and not [kʊ̀d́.dèè.kà] is based on the two-mora limit on syllables in the language and the fact that a moraic consonant can follow a long vowel (does not cause shortening).

Comment: Ooh, fascinating! Would you mind syllabifying that?

Comment: This is great, thank you! A little advanced for me, having difficulty parsing the [kʊ̀d́dèèkà] and [d́ꜜdíiji], not sure how to pronounce it (if that is IPA or something else). It looks like there is an accent on the d with [d́]. Wondering if that is the tone. Wondering how it would be pronounced, maybe if you could explain that part. I don't see how a [d] could have a tone _shift during its pronunciation_, so it must just be a tone shift relative to the surrounding letters.

Comment: Also, wondering if you have seen _accents_ (_stresses_) on consonants anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

It depends what you mean by "consonant". In Swahili you can see stress on nasals, as in *mtu* `/ˈm̩.tu/` "person". In Cantonese, similarly, you see nasals with tone: 五 *ng5* `/ŋ˩˧/` "five" versus 悟 *ng6* `/ŋ˨/` "to realize".

However, this only applies to *syllabic nasals*: nasals that can form the core of a syllable. And one common definition of "vowel" is "syllabic sound" or "sound that can form the core of a syllable". So by this definition, the first sound in *mtu* is actually a vowel.

As a general rule, stress and tone apply to *syllables* rather than to individual phonemes. So in a word like English "ample" `/ˈæm.pəl/`, the `/m/` can be called "stressed" just as much as the `/æ/` is: there's no instantaneous drop in loudness and pitch once the vowel is finished and the consonant begins.

Comment: "As a general rule." Wondering if there are any specific cases though that break the rule, or if that is what your first example was.

Comment: @LancePollard If there are any I don't know them, but I can't rule it out.

Comment: I think tone is often analyzed as a property of morae rather than of syllables.

Comment: @sumelic Fair, but is there a universal definition of morae? I generally think of morae as a language-specific division.

Comment: Different things may be "moraic" or not in different languages, but a typical example of what I was thinking of would be e.g. a language that has high-low and low-high contour tones that only occur on long vowels or diphthongs, whereas short monophthongs can only be high or low. Analyses where such contour tones are analyzed as being a high tone followed by a low tone, or vice versa, seems to be possible and commonly proposed for many languages, so I don't think the phenomenon is all that language-specific.

Comment: I think long vowels are universally analyzed as containing more than one mora (of course, the existence of long vowels in a language may be controversial). By the way, I'm just using "mora" in these comments to refer to what might be called a "timing slot" in some theories; I don't have any particularly rigorous concept in mind (I don't know enough to explain or defend some theory like that)